# How to create custom frontend php page via plugin

Tags: plugin-development, front-end

I'm new to wordpress development and was wondering how to create a custom php file (like: mysounds.php) which would use a php file in my plugin directory.

So in other words:
I create a php file in my plugin directory and create a route that users can enter in the address bar to reach that page.

How should one go about doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you just want custom content on the page? If so, a shortcode may work for that

Comment: I want to create a custom api point where I can process data coming in

Comment: Then you should have asked how to create a custom api endpoint where you can process data coming in :)

Comment: :) as a newb to wordpress the question is more general, since i want to know how to make custom pages, in this specific example its for an api ;)

Comment: a custom page and an endpoint are different things, and have different solutions.